# How to make cookie switch between on and off state with one .fadeToggle(); function

Tags: jquery, cookies

I wrote this code:

```
$("#tiger-panel-discuss").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#tiger-content").fadeToggle();
            $("#tiger-io").fadeToggle();
            $.cookie("tiger-content", "active");
            return false;
        });

        if ($.cookie("tiger-content") == "active") {
            $("#tiger-io").hide();
            $("#tiger-io-ru").hide();
            $("#tiger-content").show();
        }
```

But need a lil bit to change it, eg: @ this moment after I click on this button(#tiger-panel-discuss) I save cookie and on a page refresh it shows what I need. However, what I want to do is if s1 will click again on that button(#tiger-panel-discuss) it will clear current cookie state. So @ the end this should work like: first click = cookie is in active state, second click = cookies is in "null" state, third click will start it all over again. Like a loop.

Can some one give a hand please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#tiger-panel-discuss").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#tiger-content").fadeToggle();
            $("#tiger-io").fadeToggle();
            if ($.cookie("tiger-content") == "active") {
              $.cookie("tiger-content", "null");
            } else {
              $.cookie("tiger-content", "active");
            }
            return false;

        });
```

Comment: Nice, thank you m8, because want to get rid of my own "solution" which way longer